# tabBar in ModalBottomSheet with dynamic size Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to use a `tabBar` within a `modal Bottom Sheet` for user input.But `tabBarView` takes all the height of the page if we do not specify fixed values(Eg.height in the `container`).`Modal Bottom Sheet` default user interaction is perfect(Bottom Sheet pop Up during keyboard input).My code snippet are given below.Can you have any solution to regain the default behaviour?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Tester',
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {

Future bottomModal(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(12))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: DefaultTabController(
              length: 2,
              initialIndex: 0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.red,
                    tabs: <Widget>[
                      Tab(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.note_add),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height:
                        100,     //I want to use dynamic height instead of fixed height
                    child: TabBarView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Task'),
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              child: Text('Submit'),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            TextField(
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(hintText: 'Personal Note'),
                            ),
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Text('Submit'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => bottomModal(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            'data',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Expanded` instead of `Container(height: 100, ...` after `TabBar`.